# Put multi array into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi i got this array here and i want to put it into mysql database,
here is my array

$v = "Tom: 2000, Bob: 300, Jack: 500"

$x is Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Tom [1] => 2000 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => 300 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Jack [1] => 500 ) )

and this is my code to put it into database:

```html
$f=explode(",",$v);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($f);$i++){
$x[$i]=explode(": ",$f[$i]);

$player=$x[$i][0];
$win=$x[$i][1];
$sql         = "UPDATE scores SET win=$win WHERE player='$player'";
$result      = $conn->query( $sql );
}
```

but the problem is for loop only puts 'Tom' and '2000' (which are first) into database and nothing happens to other player's row, i think this code should work fine but i cant find what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the other records exist? I see you're doing an UPDATE and not an INSERT, so maybe the other records mismatch on "player"?

You also might want to use trim() on $player and $win, to remove any whitespace from the explode() output.

Comment: all other records exist and they match the player, i will try trim().